# Why can't c# infer casting?

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, type-conversion

So i recently started working with reflection for the first time, and found GetType() to know the original type of an object, even if it is just stored as an object.

```
foreach(object o in (IEnumerable) property.GetValue(element))
{
    List(o, verbose, int.MaxValue, subIncludes[attribute.Name], indents + 4);
}
```

So here o is actually getting passed into a generic method. I found that after getting passed in, o.GetType(); returns the actual class type and not System.Object which surprised me. For arguments sake lets say the type is Product. So if the type is already known, why is it necessary to cast o to Product like so `Product p = (Product) o;`instead of just doing `Product p = o`? Why not infer that casting is the desired outcome since the type is already known?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're asking. _"if the type is already known"_ -- known by whom? The method with the parameter of type `object` has to be able to be compiled safely without any knowledge of any of the code that might call that method. In the context of the method, the parameter is _only_ guaranteed to be `object`. Just because one caller passes `Product`, that doesn't mean _all_ callers will be passing `Product`. The compiler can't provide that `Product p = o;` is safewhen `o` is declared only to be `object`.

Comment: All that said, a) a generic method that casts arguments is almost always bad design, and b) it's not really even clear from your question what kind of inference it is you're asking about. I have tried to guess, but no good answer could be posted unless you provide better clarity for your question. Make sure that includes a [mcve] that shows _clearly_ what it is you're asking about.

Comment: Your variable `o` refers to a `Product` object under the covers. However, all the compiler knows is that the variable `o` is of type object. That you have that variable referring to a `Product` is just your executing code. Your code could assign any object (or even a value) to `o` at any time. For what it's worth, if you typed `o` as `dynamic`, you're telling the compiler, "trust me, I know what I'm doing". At that point you could call any of `Product`'s methods, but with a cost that comes from the compiler not sure that what you're doing is safe

Comment: To address it more directly (points made in other comments), languages like C#, Java, the polymorphism is implemented at runtime, i.e., at runtime only a system will know which type is contained in the object (think inheritance of same interfaces by multiple classes). This is a major reason that the type inference in these languages is weaker compared to functional languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At compile time it has no idea what `o` is.  It would be perfectly valid to use something that was not a `Product` here.

Your main question - `...instead of just doing Product p = o` - What if `Product` had an implicit operator implemented?

`public static implicit operator Product(object o)`

Then, given that you wanted to use your new, laid-back casting syntax - `Product p = o` the runtime wouldn't know which way to convert it - using the implicit conversion or your cast.  Maybe that's why this syntax is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Casting is a compile-time feature. It tells the compiler that you know what you are doing. Straight assignment as your 2nd example is evaluated at runtime.